# Using Nth selector on active class

Tags: html, css

How can i use the nth selector to add a set of styles to the last one?

I have a set of divs with only some containing a certain class. How can I add a style such as a background color to the last div containing that class.

I've tried last child and last of type. Can't seem to select the last one with the "Active" class though.

```css
div.active::after {
    content: 'ify'; 
}
div.active:last-of-type {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">Snake</div>
<div>Rabbit</div>
<div>Squirtle</div>
<div class="active">Corn</div>
<div class="active">Drake</div>
<div>Yellow</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kp0axjkq/

Comment: You can't achieve this with purely CSS.  You could add another class to the one you want to modify and use that though.

Comment: Unless the number of divs (or the position of the last `.active` div relative to the end of the list) remains the same, you'll need JS or you'll need to modify your markup.

Comment: Why don't you just use div:nth-of-type(5)? You could wrap all of those divs inside one div say class wrapper, and do this: .wrapper div:nth-of-type(5).

Comment: It's strange though that it's so simple to target only the first div with a certain class, yet impossible to target the last one. This is definitely a flaw in CSS.